# Build a time-selectable python xarray although time is not a dimension of my 3D matrix

Tags: python-xarray

I have a 3D matrix containing data of interest called iasi_allAirports of size (6, 10000, 3) with the dimensions (airport, numofprofile, level). Data can be float of nan. I also have a datetime64 3D matrix of same shape with the corresponding dates.
I want to be able to use the time selection functions of xarray like

```
xa_summer = xa[xa.dt.season=='JJA']
```

or

```
ds.sel(date="2000-01")
```

I don't understand well if I need to build a DataArray or a Dataset in my case ?
(an argument would be that the season getter is made only for DataArray)

Here are my codes to build both of them:

```
ds = xr.DataArray(iasi_allAirports,
                  coords = {'airport': listOfAirportNames, 
                            'profnum': np.arange(0, 10000 ),
                            'level': levels,
                            'date': ( ('airport', 'profnum', 'level'), timeMatrix )
                            },
                  dims = ['airport', 'profnum', 'level'] )

ds = xr.Dataset(
    { 'iasi':   (['airport', 'profnum', 'level'], iasi_allAirports) },
    coords = {'airport': listOfAirportNames, 
              'profnum': np.arange(0, 10000 ),
              'level': levels,
              'date': ( ('airport', 'profnum', 'level'), timeMatrix )
              },
)
```

In both cases, if I do

```
ds.sel(date='2019-06')
```

It says:

> dimensions or multi-index levels ['date'] do not exist

With the DataArray,

```
ds[ds.dt.season=='JJA']
```

says:

> TypeError: '.dt' accessor only available for DataArray with datetime64
> timedelta64 dtype or for arrays containing cftime datetime objects.

Is there a way to do what I want without reorganizing my matrices ?

Thank you

Comment: How is time related to the other dimensions (airport, numofprofile, level) you mention? Is time part of the numofprofile dimensions? Ideally, you can reshape your array to e.g. a 4D array, with one dimension representing time. But this does require you data to be "rectangular": e.g. the same number of times per airport, per level. If that's not the case, you can also use `.where` instead. https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html

Comment: Thanks for your help ! My data are not rectangular, I indeed managed to get something with .where

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `xarray`, but you could use `numpy` and `datetime`, with masks.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Creating random 3D data
data = np.random.random((20, 20, 20))
# Creating a 3D array of dates
base = datetime.today()
dates = np.array([base - timedelta(days=x) for x in range(20*20*20)])
dates = dates.reshape(data.shape)

# Using masks to find the data corresponding to a specific date
print(data[dates == base])
print(data[dates == dates[12, 9, 11]])
```

You can find plenty of examples on google on how to convert strings to datetime objects. For example:

```
date_string = '2021-May-20'
date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%B-%d')
```

Be careful that `datetime` objects also includes the detail about hours, minutes and seconds. So depending on the precision of your dates and how you want to select, you may have to deal with this.

Finally, note that I suggested the `datetime` module because you talked about `dates`, and it's very to deal with these. However, you can apply the same procedure only using `numpy`, and keep you array of dates as an array of strings; and still use `numpy` masks:

```
data[dates == base]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I finally managed to use the xarray and pandas time handling system (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get something with `.where`:

```
ds_summer = ds.where( (ds.time.dt.month == 6) | (ds.time.dt.month == 7) | (ds.time.dt.month == 8) )
```

But `ds.time.dt.season` does not work : "arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type"

I understood that a xarray Dataset is just an object containing several DataArray, which is convenient for me since I actually have two other DataArray (IM and IMS).
time can be put as a coordinate:

```
ds = xr.Dataset(
    { 'iasi':   (['airport', 'profnum', 'level'], iasi_allAirports),
      'IM':     (['airport', 'profnum', 'level'], IM_allAirports),
      'IMS':    (['airport', 'profnum', 'level'], IM_allAirports)   },
    coords = {'airport': listOfAirportNames, 
              'profnum': np.arange(0, iasi_allAirports.shape[1] ),
              'level': levels,
              'time': ( ('airport', 'profnum', 'level'), timeMatrix )
} )
```

or as data :

```
ds = xr.Dataset(
    { 'iasi':   (['airport', 'profnum', 'level'], iasi_allAirports),
       'IM':     (['airport', 'profnum', 'level'], IM_allAirports),
       'IMS':    (['airport', 'profnum', 'level'], IM_allAirports),
       'time': ( ['airport', 'profnum', 'level'], timeMatrix ) },
    coords = {'airport': listOfAirportNames, 
              'profnum': np.arange(0, iasi_allAirports.shape[1] ),
              'level': levels
} )
```

Both work. The difference is that time will dissappear in non-summer dates when it's put as data while it will not dissapear when it's put as coordinate.

For easier viewing, `df_summer = ds_summer.to_dataframe()` will change the matrix to a 2D pandas dataframe.